# Get partial view models in submit action of parent

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I can add multiple partialview dynamically into my page like this

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model Opto.Models.GlassOrder
...
...
...
    <div class="text-center" dir="rtl" id="ttt">
    </div>
    <a id="add1" style="cursor:pointer">add</a>
    
    <script>
    var rowNum = 0;
            $('#add1').click(function () {
                rowNum++;
                $.get('/Glasses/DisplayBill?id=' + rowNum, function (partial) {
                    console.log(partial);
                    $('#ttt').append(partial);
                });
    
            });
        </script>
```

**BillFarSighted.cshtml**

```
    @model Opto.Models.BillFarSighted
    
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            
            <div class="row form-group">
            <label asp-for="PackFactor" class="col-5 text-left col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-7">
                <select asp-for="PackFactor" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Compression>()">
                    <option selected value="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="PackFactor" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>            
            ...
...
... 
        </div>
```

**BillFarSighted.cs**

```
public partial class BillFarSighted
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long RecipeId { get; set; }
...
...
...
}
```

**GlassesController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult DisplayBill(int id)
            {
                BillFarSighted billFarSighted = new BillFarSighted() { PackFactor = 3 };
                return PartialView("BillFarSighted", billFarSighted);
            }
    
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(List<BillFarSighted> billFarSighteds)
            {
    ....
    }
```

but when I submit parent form( in create action  ), `billFarSighteds` list is empty, how can I get those partial models in controller?

Comment: Can you show us the partialview and the BillFarSighted model?

Comment: And what's the Compression?

Comment: I can not send all of details in my question because stack says it seeams too much code, compression is an enum, not important, my question is that in submit action it wont get models in partial, I am sure there is not problem in partial model, it is just because of parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to list object binding is ensuring that a sequential index in square brackets is added to the form field's name attribute e.g [0].PackFactor.

In your case, you can make the rowNum as the index.

Create.csthml

```
<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
    <div class="text-center" dir="rtl" id="ttt">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />

</form>
<a id="add1" style="cursor:pointer">add</a>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        var rowNum = 0;
        $('#add1').click(function () {
            $.get('/Glasses/DisplayBill?id=' + rowNum, function (partial) {
                console.log(partial);
                $('#ttt').append(partial);
                rowNum++;
            });
        
        });
    </script>
}
```

BillFarSighted.cshtml

```
@model BillFarSighted

<div style="display: inline-block">

    <div class="row form-group">
        <label asp-for="PackFactor" class="col-5 text-left col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-7">
            <select asp-for="PackFactor" name="[@Model.Id].PackFactor" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Compression>()">
                <option selected value="">Select</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="PackFactor" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class BillFarSighted
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long RecipeId { get; set; }
    public long PackFactor { get; set; }
}

public enum Compression
{
    AAA = 1,
    BBB = 2,
    CCC = 3,
    DDD = 4
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DisplayBill(int id)
{
    BillFarSighted billFarSighted = new BillFarSighted() { Id = id };
    return PartialView("BillFarSighted", billFarSighted);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(List<BillFarSighted> billFarSighteds)
{
    //some codes
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: it worked, I don't know how to thank you, you saved me